# Updating dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have the following code which dynamically generates an assembly and classes based on an EdmModel. This is all working fine, however I a bit confused on how I can update the assembly when the model changes.

Here are my current thoughts, either:

- Update the current classes, adding/removing properties. Adding new classes when needed.
- Create another version of the assembly, allowing me to have the two versions running at the same time (This approach is preferable as it would allow the user to access the different versions of the model, and would mean the current version could still be used while the new one was being generated)

Is it possible to run two versions of the same assembly this way? Is it possible to update a type that has already been created? Am I doing this right?

```
public class DynamicAssembyGenerator
{
    private IDictionary<string, AssemblyBuilder> _assemblyBuilders;
    private IDictionary<string, ModuleBuilder> _moduleBuilders;
    private IDictionary<string, TypeBuilder> _typeBuilders;
    private IDictionary<string, EnumBuilder> _enumBuilders;
    private IDictionary<string, Type> _types;

    public void Create(IEdmModel model)
    {
        _assemblyBuilders = model.DeclaredNamespaces.ToDictionary(declaredNamespace => declaredNamespace,
            CreateAssemblyBuilder);
        _moduleBuilders = model.DeclaredNamespaces.ToDictionary(declaredNamespace => declaredNamespace,
            declaredNamespace => CreateModuleBuilder(declaredNamespace, _assemblyBuilders[declaredNamespace]));
        _typeBuilders = new Dictionary<string, TypeBuilder>();
        _enumBuilders = new Dictionary<string, EnumBuilder>();
        _types = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        foreach (
            var edmSchemaElement in
                model.SchemaElements.Where(s => s.SchemaElementKind == EdmSchemaElementKind.TypeDefinition))
        {
            if (_moduleBuilders.ContainsKey(edmSchemaElement.Namespace))
            {
                CreateType(model, edmSchemaElement.FullName(), _moduleBuilders[edmSchemaElement.Namespace]);
            }
        }

        foreach (var assemblyBuilder in _assemblyBuilders.Values)
        {
            assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyBuilder.GetName().Name + ".dll");
        }

        foreach (var value in _types.Values)
        {
            var edmType = model.FindDeclaredType(value.FullName);
            model.SetAnnotationValue<ClrTypeAnnotation>(edmType, new ClrTypeAnnotation(value));
        }
    }

    private void CreateType(IEdmModel model, string typeName, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    {
        if (_typeBuilders.ContainsKey(typeName) || _enumBuilders.ContainsKey(typeName))
        {
            return;
        }
        var structuredType = model.FindDeclaredType(typeName) as IEdmStructuredType;
        if (structuredType != null)
        {
            var entityType = structuredType as IEdmEntityType;

            var typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder(structuredType, model, moduleBuilder);
            _typeBuilders.Add(typeName, typeBuilder);

            var constructorBuilder = CreateConstructor(typeBuilder);
            ILGenerator il = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            foreach (var edmProperty in structuredType.DeclaredProperties)
            {
                CreateProperty(edmProperty, model, typeBuilder, il,
                    entityType != null && entityType.HasDeclaredKeyProperty(edmProperty));
            }

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            _types.Add(typeName, typeBuilder.CreateType());
            return;
        }

        var enumType = model.FindDeclaredType(typeName) as IEdmEnumType;
        if (enumType != null)
        {

            var enumBuilder = CreateEnumBuilder(typeName, moduleBuilder);
            _enumBuilders.Add(typeName, enumBuilder);
            foreach (var edmEnumMember in enumType.Members)
            {
                var value = edmEnumMember.Value as EdmIntegerConstant;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    CreateEnumValue(edmEnumMember.Name, Convert.ToInt32(value.Value), enumBuilder);
                }
            }
            _types.Add(typeName, enumBuilder.CreateType());
            return;
        }
    }

    private AssemblyBuilder CreateAssemblyBuilder(string assemblyName)
    {
        var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var assemblyBuilder = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        return assemblyBuilder;
    }

    private ModuleBuilder CreateModuleBuilder(string assemblyName, AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
    {
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName, assemblyName + ".dll");
        return moduleBuilder;
    }

    private TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(IEdmStructuredType type, IEdmModel model, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    {
        var baseType = typeof(DynamicEntityBase);
        if (type.BaseType != null)
        {
            var propertyType = EdmLibHelpers.GetClrType(type.BaseType, model);
            if (propertyType == null)
            {
                var schemaElement = model.FindDeclaredType(type.BaseType.FullTypeName());
                CreateType(model, schemaElement.FullName(), _moduleBuilders[schemaElement.Namespace]);
                baseType = _types[schemaElement.FullName()];
            }
        }

        return moduleBuilder.DefineType(type.FullTypeName(), TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public, baseType);
    }

    private EnumBuilder CreateEnumBuilder(string typeName, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    {
        return moduleBuilder.DefineEnum(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
    }

    private void CreateEnumValue(string name, int value, EnumBuilder enumBuilder)
    {
        enumBuilder.DefineLiteral(name, value);
    }

    private void CreateProperty(IEdmProperty edmProperty, IEdmModel model, TypeBuilder typeBuilder, ILGenerator constructorIlGenerator, bool isKey)
    {
        var propertyType = GetPropertyType(edmProperty, model);

        var propertyName = edmProperty.Name;

        FieldBuilder fFirst;

        PropertyBuilder pFirst = CreateProperty(propertyName, propertyType, typeBuilder, out fFirst);
        SetDefaultValue(edmProperty, model, fFirst, constructorIlGenerator);

        if (isKey)
        {
            SetPropertyCustomAttribute(pFirst, typeof(KeyAttribute));
        }

        if (edmProperty.VocabularyAnnotations(model).Any(v => v.Term.FullName() == CoreVocabularyConstants.Computed))
        {
            SetPropertyCustomAttribute(pFirst, typeof(ComputedAttribute));
        }

        if (edmProperty.PropertyKind == EdmPropertyKind.Navigation)
        {
            if (edmProperty.Type.IsCollection())
            {
                CreateProperty(propertyName + "Ids", typeof(IList<string>), typeBuilder, out fFirst);
                var listType = typeof(List<string>);
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, listType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fFirst);
            }
            else
            {
                CreateProperty(propertyName + "Id", typeof(string), typeBuilder, out fFirst);
            }
        }
    }

    private static PropertyBuilder CreateProperty(string propertyName, Type propertyType, TypeBuilder typeBuilder, out FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)
    {
        fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder pFirst = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName,
                PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        //Getter
        MethodBuilder mFirstGet = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public |
            MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator firstGetIL = mFirstGet.GetILGenerator();

        firstGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        firstGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        firstGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        //Setter
        MethodBuilder mFirstSet = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public |
            MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator firstSetIL = mFirstSet.GetILGenerator();

        firstSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        firstSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        firstSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        firstSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        pFirst.SetGetMethod(mFirstGet);
        pFirst.SetSetMethod(mFirstSet);

        return pFirst;
    }

    private static void SetPropertyCustomAttribute(PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, Type attributeType)
    {
        var attributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attributeType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]),
            new object[0]);
        propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);
    }

    private Type GetPropertyType(IEdmProperty edmProperty, IEdmModel model)
    {
        var edmPropertyType = GetEdmType(edmProperty.Type);
        var propertyType = EdmLibHelpers.GetClrType(edmPropertyType, model);
        if (propertyType == null)
        {
            var schemaElement = model.FindDeclaredType(edmPropertyType.Definition.FullTypeName());
            CreateType(model, schemaElement.FullName(), _moduleBuilders[schemaElement.Namespace]);
            propertyType = _typeBuilders[schemaElement.FullName()];
        }

        if (edmProperty.Type.IsCollection())
        {
            var listType = typeof(IList<>);
            propertyType = listType.MakeGenericType(propertyType);
        }
        return propertyType;
    }

    private IEdmTypeReference GetEdmType(IEdmTypeReference type)
    {
        if (type.IsCollection())
        {
            var collectionType = type.AsCollection();
            return collectionType.CollectionDefinition().ElementType;
        }
        else
        {
            return type; ;
        }
    }

    private void SetDefaultValue(IEdmProperty property, IEdmModel model, FieldBuilder builder, ILGenerator constructorIlGenerator)
    {
        if (!property.Type.IsNullable)
        {
            var propertyType = GetPropertyType(property, model);
            if (property.Type.IsComplex())
            {
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, propertyType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, builder);
            }
            else if (property.Type.IsCollection())
            {
                var listType = typeof(List<>);
                var collectionType = listType.MakeGenericType(propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, collectionType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
                constructorIlGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, builder);
            }
        }
    }

    private ConstructorBuilder CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
    {
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                            MethodAttributes.Public |
                            MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                            MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
                            CallingConventions.Standard,
                            new Type[0]);

        return constructor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Update the current classes, adding/removing properties.

Not possible. Once you call the `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` the type you created can't be removed/modified.

- Adding new classes when needed.

Possible without problems. You can use the types you define in your `AssemblyBuilder` without saving it, so it is possible to add new types.

- Create another version of the assembly, allowing me to have the two versions running at the same time

No problem here.

- Is it possible to run two versions of the same assembly this way?

It wouldn't be the same assembly for .NET... What do they have in common? Your abstract concept that "they are the same"? But the .NET can't look into your brain :-)

Comment: @xanatos they are the same it the fact they have the same namespace and same class names. The only difference might be 1 extra property added to 1 class

Comment: @MikeNorgate The `Type` objects and the `Assembly` objects are distinct, so they are distinct. You are using them through reflection...

Comment: @leppie Wow... I hadn't ever heard of `MethodRental`... Nearly useless but funny...

Comment: @xanatos so to make sure I understand, having two types with the same name is OK and won't cause problems when getting that type

Comment: @MikeNorgate If you use the `Type.GetType(string)` static method, there is no problem, because this function doesn't work with dynamically created assemblies :-), but if you use the `Assembly.GetType(string)` instance method, then even having two assemblies with the same name isn't a problem (because you already have a reference to the "right" assembly)... The same if you directy use the `Type` obtained by the `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` instance method.